# SelfAdjointMatrix error in the Matrix Type

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I have created this method to compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of selfadjoint matrices. Yet, when I compile it, I get an error in the `Tridiagonalization.h` header from Eigen3 library. I think the problem is in the `MatrixType` that  I pass (`Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, DIMENSION>`), but I have no clue how to solve this. Does anyone know if I should change the `MatrixType`? If so, which type should I use?

```
 static void calculate(const Eigen::Matrix<float, DIMENSION, -1> &matrix,
                          Eigen::Matrix<float, DIMENSION, 1> &mean,
                          Eigen::Matrix<float, DIMENSION, DIMENSION> &eigenVectors,
                          Eigen::Matrix<float, DIMENSION, 1> &eigenValues,
                          Method method = SLOW)
    {
        mean = matrix.rowwise().mean();
        Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, DIMENSION> meanCentered = (matrix.colwise() - mean).transpose();

Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, DIMENSION> > solver(meanCentered, Eigen::ComputeFullV);
```

```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Eigen3\include\eigen3\Eigen\src/Eigenvalues/Tridiagonalization.h(434,52): error C2672: 'Eigen::internal::tridiagonalization_inplace_selector<MatrixType,-1,false>::run': no matching overloaded function found [C:\Users\JumpStart\repo-git\segmentationcpp\PlaneDetection\CommandLineOption\out\build\x64-release\src\planeprocessing_lib.vcxproj]
rloaded function found [C:\Users\JumpStart\repo-git\segmentationcpp\PlaneDetection\CommandLineOption\out\build\x64-release\src\planeprocessing_lib.vcxproj]e_selector<MatrixType,-1,false>::run': no matching ove
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Eigen3\include\eigen3\Eigen\src/Eigenvalues/Tridiagonalization.h(434,52): error C2672: 'Eigen::internal::tridiagonalization_inplace_selector<MatrixType,-1,false>::run': no matching overloaded function found [C:\Users\JumpStart\repo-git\segmentationcpp\PlaneDetection\CommandLineOption\out\build\x64-release\src\planeprocessing_lib.vcxproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Eigen3\include\eigen3\Eigen\src/Eigenvalues/Tridiagonalization.h(434,52): error C2672: 'Eigen::internal::tridiagonalization_inplace_selector<MatrixType,-1,false>::run': no matching overloaded function found [C:\Users\JumpStart\repo-git\segmentationcpp\PlaneDetection\CommandLineOption\out\build\x64-release\src\planeprocessing_lib.vcxproj]
rloaded function found [C:\Users\JumpStart\repo-git\segmentationcpp\PlaneDetection\CommandLineOption\out\build\x64-release\src\planeprocessing_lib.vcxproj]e_selector<MatrixType,-1,false>::run': no matching ove
```

Comment: Have you tried switching "-1" and "DIMENSION" ? Like in the header of your function `Eigen::Matrix<float, DIMENSION, -1>` ?

Comment: `SelfAdjointEigenSolver` only makes sense with square (symmetric) matrices, so why not use either `Matrix<float, -1, -1>` or `Matrix<float, DIMENSION, DIMENSION>`. Also, for "code is not working" problems **always** provide a [mre], in your case is `DIMENSION` a global constant? Or a template parameter? Or ...?